# Psexec with Powershell

Tags: powershell, psexec

I try to realize a Gui with psexec and powershell, and my first step is to execute file so I have a button to select file :

```
 $button2_OnClick= 
{
    $global:OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $global:OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $global:OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    write-host $global:OpenFileDialog.FileName
}
```

And another to execute psexec

```
$button1_OnClick= 
{
        Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Temp\PsExec.exe" -ArgumentList "/Accepteula -c \\<ComputerName> $global:OpenFileDialog.FileName" -Wait
}
```

But it's doesn't works do you know why ?

Thank you

Comment: Because you can't do a property lookup (`.FileName`) inside a string. Try it with a `$()` subexpression like `$($global:OpenFileDialog.FileName)`

Comment: Thank you TessellatingHeckler ! And sorry for the duplicate